# ¿Como puedo destruir la SESSION de una cuenta eliminada desde la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, session

actualmente me encuentro elaborando un panel de administración con PHP, MYSQL, resulta que he logrado hacer el sistema de cuentas pero actualmente poseo un error, y es que deseo que al poder eliminar la información de la base de dato se elimine la sesión abierta.

Me explico con un ejemplo: Digamos que el usuario B tiene acceso al panel de administración logueandose con su cuenta almacenada en mi base de datos, entonces por cualquier razon este usuario fue expulsado del equipo y al eliminar su cuenta desde la base de datos, su sesión se mantiene abierta y puede seguir manipulando el panel de administración.

[image: IMAGEN 1]

En mi base de datos se encuentra la tabla users donde se almacena a todos los usuarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces que al eliminarlo de la base de datos su sesión se cierre también y cuando intente ingresar al panel lo redireccione a la pagina de login.php y no pueda seguir manipulando el panel debido a que su cuenta fue eliminada.

**INDENTIFICADOR DEL PANEL DE ADMINISTRACIÓN**

```
function usersOnly($redirect = '/admin/login.php'){
    if (empty($_SESSION['id'])){
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Necesitas loguearte primero';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'error';
        header('location: ' . '/admin/login.php');
        exit(0);
}
}

function adminOnly($redirect = '/admin/login.php'){
    if (empty($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['admin'])){
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'No estas autorizado';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'error';
        header('location: ' . '/admin/login.php');
        exit(0);
}}
```

**EDIT: Conexión con la base de datos**

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db_name = 'blog';

$conn = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Database error connection' . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso que planteas no debería representar ningún inconveniente pues, en las variables de sesión, guardarás su `id` de usuario pero nada te impide refrescar a qué tiene acceso cada vez que recargas la página.

Me explico: con las variables de sesión evitas pedirle la contraseña al usuario cada vez que recarga una página dentro de su sesión, pero no te cuesta nada, a partir del `id` del usuario, comprobar a si aún tiene acceso al panel de administración y, si ya no lo tiene, cerrarle la sesión.

Lo que te está sucediendo es que has montado un club y has repartido carnets a los socios, pero no compruebas los pagos desde que se dieron de alta y, de esta forma, no te enteras de cuando dejan de pagar sus cuotas. ¿Cómo lo arreglas? No te queda más remedio que comprobando los pagos cada vez que hacen uso del club. Con el carnet `$_SESSION` no es suficiente. Está bien para los primeros días, pero no vale para siempre. Debes comprobar los pagos con la `query`.

Siendo prácticos, deberías sustituir ese `empty($_SESSION['admin'])` que te impide estar al día de lo último que se registra en la base de datos,
por un `!$this->check_admin($_SESSION['id'])` donde `check_admin()` lo puedes definir como:

```
function check_admin($id){
    return $this->conn->query("
        SELECT * FROM tu_tabla_de_usuarios
          WHERE id=".($id*1).";
    ")->fetch_assoc()['admin'];
}
```

O su equivalente en PDO o consulta preparada, suponiendo que en `$this->conn` tienes un objeto `mysqli`.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola, una pregunta en caso de que trabaje con MySQLi como podría modificarlo porque me esta dando este error **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context** | he editado la pregunta agregando la conexión con la base de datos usando MySQLi y muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si decides renunciar a la programación orientada a objetos y optas por la procedimental, tendrás que pasarle tu `$conn` como un parámetro más a tus funciones. Yo optaría por crearme una clase que lo englobe todo y continuar usando el `$this`

Comment: Oh listo disculpa había cometido un error, muchísimas gracias y feliz año!.